# Java Streams in Map

Tags: java, java-stream

```
Map<Integer,String> maper = new HashMap<>();
maper.put(1, "Naveen");

Map<Integer,Map<Integer,String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put(1, maper);

Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Map<Integer,String>>> mapOne = new HashMap<>();
mapOne.put(1, map1);
```

How to get the String value from mapOne using streams in Java 8?

Comment: Why do you need streams for this? Is `mapOne.get(1).get(1).get(1)` not enough?

Comment: If you try to learn how streams work with this example you can learn it from an online tutorial like: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm . But if you are really want to use this kind of structure for your data I would suggest that you make your own object which contains the data in a structure which is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question would just be:

```
mapOne.get(1).get(1).get(1)
```

where each `get` gets the inner map, or in the case of the last `get`, gets the final value.

Since you mentioned streams, I think you probably meant to ask how to flatten the nested map so that you can get the strings in the innermost map as a collection.  In that case, you should use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-). N calls to `flatMap` is required for a map nested N levels deep.

```
mapOne.values().stream()
    .flatMap(x -> x.values().stream())
    .flatMap(x -> x.values().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList()) // or toSet()
```

Comment: Thanks. but in the above answer what if i wanted to validate the key for each nested map

Comment: @M.NAVEENKUMAR Can you explain what you mean by "validate the key"? This extra requirement doesn't seem to be in the original question. Can you show some sample inputs and outputs?